# Oracle disaster recovery on Linux

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

My Oracle database is stored on a Linux system. That Linux system is down. So I want to restore my Oracle database as soon as I set up the Linux system. I don't know how to restore it. Can anyone help guide me to restore and recover my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your disks intact?

If only the machine crashed and a reboot can bring it back to life, Oracle will recover itself automatically when you start it. They call that an "instance failure".

If however, your disk is lost, you will need to restore from a backup using Oracle's Recovery Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_database_Backup_and_Recovery_FAQ